# Can chaos monkey be used with GCE instances built via jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, spinnaker, chaos

Currently, the builds are handled by jenkins, this is our chosen orchestrator. According to the Chaos Monkey deploy guide:

"To use this version of Chaos Monkey, you must be using Spinnaker to manage your applications."

My assumption from that is that unless we are using Spinnaker to deploy our applications, we cannot implement chaos monkey.

Can I use chaos monkey without using spinnaker in Google Compute Engine?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Kubernetes Engine, you can use some of the simpler variations of chaos monkey for Kubernetes. [See this example running with kubernetes-pod-chaos-monkey](https://blog.loadmill.com/run-chaos-experiments-without-risking-your-job-2c8a5f4b0bfc)

Answer (score 0):

Chaos Monkey is tightly integrated with Spinnaker. It relies on the Spinnaker APIs to terminate instances, retrieves deployment information from Spinnaker, and is configured using the Spinnaker UI. You must be managing your apps with Spinnaker to use Chaos Monkey to terminate instances.

You can find this third party [article](https://blog.spinnaker.io/running-chaos-monkey-on-spinnaker-google-compute-engine-gce-155dc52f20ef) to setting up and running Chaos Monkey on Google Compute Engine (GCE).